Largest prime number with +, -, ÷
This is inspired by this great puzzle

What is the largest prime number that can be made using the integers from 1 to 10 under the following conditions:

Addition, subtraction, division are allowed.
Multiplication and other operations are not allowed
All numbers must be used exactly once


Last condicition is superfluous. What about concatenation - is it allowed?

I believe the answer will be

 $$907,199$$

obtained through

 $$ 10 \div (2 \div 3 \div 4 \div 5 \div 6 \div 7 \div 8 \div 9) - 1 = \frac{10!}{4}-1 = 907,199$$

Note that

 adding 1 at the end instead of subtracting doesn't yield a prime number, as $$907,201 = 53 \times 17117$$


Nice try as 10/(1/2/4/5/6/7/8/9)+3=1209603 is not a prime. But I think something better may be achieved creating two values very close to each other and subtract them.
.

I figured out pretty quickly that removing a 2, 3, or 4 wouldn't work because the remaining factorial would be divisible by what you've removed due to having 8 or 9 in it. I don't think the method you've described will be able to net a very high number, but you're welcome to try.

Note: variations such as 9 / (2/3/4/5/6/7/8/10) - 1 achieve the same 907,199.

Yeah, you can swap around the positions of all the numbers bar 1 and 2 and the sum will still be the same. I don't think it's possible to get any higher with swaps though.
